# Userscript - Replace a variable's property with a function

Tags: javascript, userscripts

A website has the following code:

```
    var Items = {
        drop: function (a, b, d) {
            if (!(typeof a == "undefined" || typeof sockets[a.id] == "undefined")) {
                SSocket.send(sockets[a.id], {
                    action: "item_drop",
                    data: {
                        id: d
                    }
                });
                Inventory.add(a, d)
            }
        },
        give_to_player: function (a, b) {
            Items.drop(a, void 0, b)
        },
        take_from_player: function (a, b) {
            var d = clients[a];
            Inventory.remove(d, b);
            Player.send_inventory(d.id)
        },
    };
```

I am trying to replace the give_to_player property with my own function using a userscript. However, I am having zero luck doing so. I am familiar with javascript injection and the variable scope.

I have tried the following:

```
Object.defineProperty(window.Item, 'give_to_player', {
    value:
        function(a,b){
            console.log('Change occured');
        }
});
```

This does not generate any errors, however the change does not take hold and the console remains empty. I have tried Object.defineProperties as well with no luck.

Finally the following code failed to produce results either:

```
window.Item.give_to_player = function(a,b){ console.log('Change occured');};
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

I am using Chrome to run my userscripts.

Comment: if you want to change that property... just change it. what is the problem? what do you try to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to change the contents of the function so that particular function does something other than what the original author wrote. I don't have access to his source code so I can't just change it myself. Hence the userscript.

Comment: If the variable is called **Items** it should be accessed with that name, not **Item**, i.e. `window.Items = ...`.

Comment: why does it seem like you're trying to cheat to me?

Comment: Not trying to cheat. Working on userscripts to modify the UI for a browser game as it's still new and the UI sucks.

RobG - typo on my part when writing up the question. Sorry.

Comment: It's not clear what scope `Items` (or `Item`) is in, but it is NOT in the window scope.  You did not show us enough of the relevant code.  Link to the target page.  When you are on the target page and enter `Items` in the Chrome console, what is the result?

Answer (score 1):

The second method would work if you change the name to `Items` with a s and drop the window in the method to just `Items.give_to_player = function(a,b){ console.log('Change occured');};`.

EDIT: the `var` in `var Items` makes the method not accessible thru the window scope. if the var was dropped this `window.Items.give_to_player` won't throw error but since its there you'll not need to use the window in front of Items.(if that makes sense)

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Za4cE/)

side note: your error

```
window.Items.give_to_player = function(a,b){ console.log('Change occured');};

// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'give_to_player' of undefined
```

Answer (score -1):

I really don't know how the rest of code looks like (if that object is in some particular scope, deeply nested or what) but if `Items` object is in global scope you can define AFTER that object (and its properties definition) again that property and that should override the previous one:

```
Items.give_to_player: function () {
    //write your own function
}
```

But I'm not sure if this will work as long as I have so little information.